# Salesforce - Remove unwanted JSON Data for REST Class

Tags: json, salesforce, apex

Here is some sample json data that I am parsing:

```
{
  "lead_id": "TeSter-123-ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ-abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz-0123456789-AaBbCcDdEeFfGgHhIiJjKkLl",
  "user_column_data": [
    {
      "column_name": "First Name",
      "string_value": "FirstName",
      "column_id": "FIRST_NAME"
    },
    {
      "column_name": "Last Name",
      "string_value": "LastName",
      "column_id": "LAST_NAME"
    },
    {
      "column_name": "User Phone",
      "string_value": "+16505550123",
      "column_id": "PHONE_NUMBER"
    },
    {
      "column_name": "User Email",
      "string_value": "test@example.com",
      "column_id": "EMAIL"
    },
    {
      "column_name": "City",
      "string_value": "Mountain View",
      "column_id": "CITY"
    },
    {
      "column_name": "Region",
      "string_value": "California",
      "column_id": "REGION"
    },
    {
      "column_name": "Company Name",
      "string_value": "CompanyName",
      "column_id": "COMPANY_NAME"
    }
  ],
  "api_version": "1.0",
  "form_id": 15016502442,
  "campaign_id": 12582701989,
  "google_key": "test",
  "is_test": true,
  "gcl_id": "TeSter-123-ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ-abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz-0123456789-AaBbCcDdEeFfGgHhIiJjKkLl",
  "adgroup_id": 20000000000,
  "creative_id": 30000000000
```

And here is my rest class:

```
@RestResource(urlMapping='/Lead/*')
global with sharing class MyRestResource {
  
  @HttpPost
    global static String doPost(List<Map<String,String>>user_column_data) {
        Map<String, String> user_data = new Map<String,String>();
        
        for( Map<String,String> field_data : user_column_data){
        user_data.put( field_data.get('column_id'), field_data.get('string_value') );
        }
        
        Lead newLead = new Lead();
        newLead.Status = 'New';
        newLead.Company = user_data.get('COMPANY_NAME');
        newLead.Phone = user_data.get('PHONE_NUMBER');
        newLead.Email = user_data.get('EMAIL');
        newLead.FirstName = user_data.get('FIRST_NAME');
        newLead.LastName = user_data.get('LAST_NAME');
        try{
            insert newLead;
        }
        catch (exception e){
            System.debug('Failure');
        }
        return newLead.Id;
        
    }
}
```

After deleting:

```
"lead_id": "TeSter-123-ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ-abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz-0123456789-AaBbCcDdEeFfGgHhIiJjKkLl",
```

......

```
"api_version": "1.0",
  "form_id": 15016502442,
  "campaign_id": 12582701989,
  "google_key": "test",
  "is_test": true,
  "gcl_id": "TeSter-123-ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ-abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz-0123456789-AaBbCcDdEeFfGgHhIiJjKkLl",
  "adgroup_id": 20000000000,
  "creative_id": 30000000000
```

The record is created within the org through workbench.

I'm not too sure how but how can I ignore any JSON element that doesn't have a columnID so I don't have parse errors.

My idea would be to only capture the information within the brackets from user_column_data but I'm not entirely proficient with Java/Apex so I've been running into a couple errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution:

```
@RestResource(urlMapping='/Lead/*')
global with sharing class GoogleCampaignRestResource {

    public class User_column_data {
        public String column_name; 
        public String string_value;
        public String column_id;
    }

    public class LeadWrapper {
        public String lead_id;
        public List<User_column_data> user_column_data;
        public String api_version;
        public Long form_id;
        public Long campaign_id;
        public String google_key;
        public Boolean is_test;
        public String gcl_id;
        public Long adgroup_id;
        public Long creative_id;

        public Map<String, String> getDataMap() {
            Map<String, String> dataMap = new Map<String, String>();

            for (User_column_data data : this.user_column_data) {
                dataMap.put(data.column_id, data.string_value);
            }

            return dataMap;
        }
    }

    @HttpPost
    global static String doPost() {
        RestRequest request = RestContext.request;
        RestResponse response = RestContext.response;
         
        String json = request.requestBody.toString();
        LeadWrapper leadData = (LeadWrapper) System.JSON.deserialize(json, LeadWrapper.class);

        Map<String, String> user_data = leadData.getDataMap();
         
        Lead newLead = new Lead(
            Status = 'New',
            Company = user_data.get('COMPANY_NAME'),
            Phone = user_data.get('PHONE_NUMBER'),
            Email = user_data.get('EMAIL'),
            FirstName = user_data.get('FIRST_NAME'),
            LastName = user_data.get('LAST_NAME'),
            LeadSource = 'Google AdWords'
        );
        insert newLead;

        return newLead.Id;
    }
}
```